# Which of these DB designs is better?

Tags: sql, database

I'm trying to understand some concepts of DB desing.

I have three tables:

```
Movies (id,title)
1 - The godfather
2 - Matrix


Attribute (id,name)
1 - Country
2 - Type

Attribute Value(attribute_id,id,value)

1,1,USA
1,2,Japan
2,1,Thriller
2,2,Comedy
```

and I would like to link movies with one and just one attribute and with one attribute value

IE: Godfather, Country: USA, Type: Crime

I'm trying to find out which of the next is the best solution for linking attributes to a movie. I can see 4 diferent options:

**Schema A**

[image: Schema A!]

Problem I see is that I can't restrict multiple attribute_values of same attribute for a movie. I.E ("godfather","USA","JAPAN") is a valid statement
The restriction should be controlled by the application

**Schema B**

[image: Schema B]

It's almost the same as Schema A but making Attribute Value a weak entity. I think this has no effect at database level but it would make a bit harder to fetch attribute values as you need attribute key as well. This schema allows to have same category repated, with diferent values, multiple times, so I don't think is a good option neither. As well as option A, the restriction should be controlled by the application

("godfather","Country:USA","Country:JAPAN") is a valid statement

**Schema C**

[image: Schema C]

I think this is the correct one as now we can’t add more than 1 attribute of the same type to a movie
“Godfather”, “USA”, “JAPAN” is not a valid insertion!

But I can't tell if making attribute_value a weak entity would be correct or not, better or worse :S

**Schema D**

[image: Schema D]

As I said, same as C but with composite key in attribute_value.
I’m not sure if this break some database normalization rules. In case this is OK, which table should be referenced from movie_attribute_value for field attribute_id? Attribute ID from Attribute table or AttributeID from AttributeValue table? Is ok to have a composite foreing key and use only a part of the key in the PK ?

Could you please explain with option is better and why?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT

I understood the problems of such a design like this, what a EAV schema is and the needed to avoid this type of schema unless in a situation with a lot of changes in the attribute table. Unfortunately this is my scenario, the attributes of the movie are defined by users, so I don't have a way to know which attributes are going to be used. I have to read them and display to another users to fill them. I think Schema C is correct but would like to know what's the problem of using schemas A and B and letting developers to control the restrictions (one same type  attribute per movie) in the code

As well would be great if somebody can explaing the benefits and pitfalls of using Schema D (composite K) instead of Schema C and if it's OK to have only some fields of a foreign key (attribute_value_id,attribute_id) as PK (movie_id, attribute_id)

Comment: Schema (E) - none of the above. Don't do this EAV (Entity-Attribute-Value) schema - it's hard to query, it's a pain to use - use normalized, proper relational tables (`Movie` with a bunch of attributes, `Country`, `MovieGenre` etc.)

Comment: Hi Marc. It would be great if you can provide a valid design other than EAV for this scenario, just for learning purposes

Comment: Please define "weak entity".

Comment: According to wikipedia: "In a relational database, a weak entity is an entity that cannot be uniquely identified by its attributes alone; therefore, it must use a foreign key in conjunction with its attributes to create a primary key."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Marc_s comments, EAV designs have a whole bunch of drawbacks. In the case of a movie collection, you know the schema, and it's unlikely to change randomly, and when it does change (e.g. you need to add a flag "available in 4K"), it's probably a big deal.

Ask yourself how you will retrieve all films for a given genre, or all films available in both the US and Japan, or all comedies available in the US but not Japan - you'll very quickly see the limits of EAV.

To answer your question - none of your designs work for me - there are too many tables that don't earn their keep. If you really must go EAV, I'd suggest:

```
MOVIES
---------
MovieID
.....


ATTRIBUTES
--------------
AttributeID
AttributeName

MOVIE_ATTRIBUTES
------------
MovieID
AttributeID
Value
```

If you want to provide the list of valid value, the easiest way is to query the "movie attributes" table and retrieve previous entries for that combination of movie and attribute - keeping your schema simple will make life MUCH easier.

If you really want to put the values in a separate table, schema D appears correct.

Schema C says:

- for each movie, I have 0 or more movie_attibute_value records
- for each movie_attribute_value_record, I have 0 or more attribute_value records
- for each attribute_value record, i have zero or more attribute/value combinations.

I believe the last statement is incorrect.

Comment: The problem with your suggestion is that I won't be able to provide to users a list of valid values in a combobox. Could you please post which design would you use for this kind of scenario?

Comment: @Aitor This has turned into an [**XY Problem**](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). Ie You did not mention combo boxes in Question. **Edit** your question to show this.

Comment: @davidstrachan just wanted to show the weakness of his proposal. Is not related to show the data in a combobox but to get the possible values from a table as explained in my first diagram

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to lump all the attributes in the one table, along with a defined type of attribute. Thus:

```
Movies
------
MovieId


AttributeTypes
---------------
AttributeTypeId
Description


Attributes
---------
AttributeId
AttributeTypeId
Description


MovieAttributes
---------------
MovieId
AttributeId
```

It could make for awkward queries, but that really depends on how the stored data will be used.

(In other words, yes, I agree with prior posts, and recommend avoiding EAV structures.)